# Facebook: Anyone knows why I can't get the event's I'm attending?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get a list of facebook events I'm attending. I have these codes:

```
$fql = "SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 100000266996446 AND rsvp_status = 'attending'";

$param  =   array(
 'method'    => 'fql.query',
 'query'     => $fql,
 'callback'  => ''
);

$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);

foreach( $fqlResult as $keys => $values ){
    echo "<div>" . $values['eid'] . "[][]</div>";
}
```

Many thanks for any help! :)

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm getting a blank page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code, please note that you cannot do it if you're using a profile uid. It will only work with fan pages.